# ¿Como declaró la longitud de un array dentro de una clase por medio del constructor?

Tags: c++

```
class Resistencia{
    public:
        Resistencia(int nResistores);
        void setResistor(int Indice, float Valor);
        float getResistor(int Indice) const;
        bool getParalelo() const;
        bool setSerie() const;


    private:

        float resitor[];
        double rEqui;
};
```

En el anterior código tengo la clase resistencia, sin embargo tengo problemas para desde el constructor poder declarar o asignar una longitud al arreglo.

```
Resistencia::Resistencia(int nResistores)
{
     resitor[nResistores];
}
```

Este es el constructor de la clase, pero al momento de compilar lanza una advertencia, 
**In constructor 'Resistencia::Resistencia(int)':|5|warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]|

Tengo muy poca experiencia, agradeceria su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Resistencia::Resistencia(int nResistores)
> {
>     resitor[nResistores];
> }
> ```
>
> Al momento de compilar lanza una advertencia:
>
> ```
> In constructor 'Resistencia::Resistencia(int)' warning: statement has no effect
> ```

Lo que esa advertencia te está indicando es: "*Cuidado: la sentencia no tiene efecto*".

Estás aplicando el operador de indexado (los corchetes `[]`) sobre un puntero (`Resistencia::resitor`) lo cuál devuelve un valor, así que tu código sería más o menos equivalente a:

```
Resistencia::Resistencia(int nResistores)
{
    1; // Cuidado: la sentencia no tiene efecto.
}
```

Si la posición `nResistores` de `Resistencia::resitor` contuviera un `1`, en ese punto del código le dices al compilador: Uno, lo cuál es una sentencia que (como advierte el compilador) no tiene efecto alguno.

#### Propuesta.

Olvídate de usar un puntero en crudo, usa `std::vector`:

```
struct Resistencia{
    Resistencia(int nResistores) : resitor(nResistores) {}
    //                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- longitud en el constructor
    void setResistor(int Indice, float Valor);
    float getResistor(int Indice) const;
    bool getParalelo() const;
    bool setSerie() const;

private:
    std::vector<float> resitor;
    double rEqui;
};
```